# Why does this while-loop not run?

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve a set of differential equations numerically. During the process I need to use a discrete variable to annul one of my integration variables. But I also need to control what happens at r->Infinity for another variable (because for this one I have a boundary condition and not an initial condition). *Mathematica* says that it can not deal with discrete variables and boundary conditions. So I wanted to use a while-loop, but it doesn't work and i don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
β = - 4.5 ;
Γ = 2.34 ;
K = 0.0195 ;
ρ0 = 10^(18) ;
c = 3 10^8 ;
G = 6.67 10^(-11) ;
ϵ[r_] = (ρ[r] + K ρ0 (ρ[r]/ρ0)^Γ) c^2 ;
p[r_] = K ρ0 (ρ[r]/ρ0)^Γ c^2 (Γ - 1) ; 
A[r_] = Exp[(1/2) β φ[r]^2] ;    
Eqn1 = (μ'[r] - (4 Pi G/c^2) r^2 (ϵ[r]/c^2) (A[r])^4 - (1/2) r (r - 2 μ[r]) (ψ[r])^2 == 0) ;
Eqn2 = (ν'[r] - (8 Pi G/c^4) r^2 (A[r])^4 p[r]/(r - 2 μ[r]) - r (ψ[r])^2 + 2 μ[r]/(r (r - 2 μ[r])) == 0) ;
Eqn3 = (φ'[r] - ψ[r] == 0) ;    
Eqn4 = (ψ'[r] - (4 Pi G/c^4) r (A[r])^4/(r - 2 μ[r]) (β φ[r] (ϵ[r] - 3 p[r]) + r ψ[r] (ϵ[r] - p[r])) + 2 (r - μ[r]) ψ[r]/(r (r - 2 μ[r])) == 0) ;   
Eqn5 = (p'[r] + on[r]((ϵ[r] + p[r]) ((4 Pi G/c^4) r^2 (A[r])^4 p[r]/(r - 2 μ[r]) + (1/2) r (ψ[r])^2 + μ[r]/(r (r - 2 μ[r])) + β φ[r] ψ[r])) == 0) ;

a = 1 ;
n = 1 ;

While[Abs[a] > 0.0009,   
  {sol = 
    NDSolve[
      {Eqn1, Eqn2, Eqn3, Eqn4, Eqn5, 
       μ[10^(-8)] == 0, ν[10^(-8)] == 0, ρ[10^(-8)] == ρ0, ψ[10^(-8)] == 0, 
       φ[10^(-8)] == 0.5, on[10^(-8)] == 1,   
       WhenEvent[ρ[r] < 3 10^(17), on[r] -> 0],   
       WhenEvent[ρ[r] < 3*10^(17), ρ[r] -> 10^(-20)]}, 
      {μ[r], ν[r], ρ[r], ψ[r], φ[r]}, {r,10^(-8), 30000},   
      DiscreteVariables -> {on[r] ∈ {0, 1}},   
      Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}], a = φ[10^9] /. sol}; n++]; 
  {n, Abs[a]}
```

It always gives me back `{2, {0.97887}}` which violates the while-loop condition.

Comment: Your `Eqn4` contains a syntax error

Comment: Could you tell me where please ? I must admit that I don't see.

Comment: There is an unclosed parenthesis there

Comment: You're right thanks ! but it is ok on my computer so the problem doesn't come from there

Comment: What are you changing from one iteration to the next? `n` is just a counter

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer. I don't have time to do all your debugging. Your `While`-loop is syntactically unsound and has semantic problems as well.

The following edit of your loop addresses the syntax issues but is probably worthless because of the remaining semantic issues. However, it might move you forward some on your debugging.

```
While[Abs[a] > 0.0009,
  sol = 
    NDSolve[
     {Eqn1, Eqn2, Eqn3, Eqn4, Eqn5,
      μ[10^(-8)] == 0, ν[10^(-8)] == 0, ρ[10^(-8)] == ρ0, ψ[10^(-8)] == 0, 
      φ[10^(-8)] == 0.5, on[10^(-8)] == 1,
      WhenEvent[ρ[r] < 3 10^(17), on[r] -> 0],
      WhenEvent[ρ[r] < 3*10^(17), ρ[r] -> 10^(-20)]},
     {μ[r], ν[r], ρ[r], ψ[r], φ[r]}, {r, 10^(-8), 30000}, 
     DiscreteVariables -> {on[r] ∈ {0, 1}},
     Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]; 
  a = (φ[r] /. sol /. r -> 10.^9); 
  n++]
```

One glaring semantic error is that you solve over the range `{r, 10^(-8), 30000}`, but then want to evaluate `φ[r]` at  10.^9, which is outside that range.